# Blackberry -- Listfield with transparent rows

Tags: blackberry

I have a screen with a background image being rendered like so:

```
     bg = new VerticalFieldManager(
            VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH |
            VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT |
            VerticalFieldManager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR |
            VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR |
            VerticalFieldManager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL |
            VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL) {
        //Override the paint method to draw the background image.
        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            //Draw the background image and then call paint.
            graphics.drawBitmap(Graphics.getScreenWidth()/2 - bgBitmap.getWidth()/2,
                    Graphics.getScreenHeight()/2 - bgBitmap.getHeight()/2, 
                    bgBitmap.getWidth(), bgBitmap.getHeight(), bgBitmap, 0, 0);
            super.paint(graphics);
        }
    };
    add(bg);
```

Then I'm adding any fields for the screen to this manager. I have a ListField that I'd like to see the background through.  When the screen is first rendered, all is well.  I can see the image.  As soon as I scroll down, select something and unselect it, the background disappears (turns white).

Do I need to do something special when drawing my list rows in order to make them truly transparent after the selection color is gone?

NOTE:  I've found that this happens no matter what field is drawn on top of the background.  It displays correctly until the selection color is drawn for a given focusable field and then you select something else.  All the area that was filled with the selection color turns to the default white after unselecting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overriding moveFocus() in my custom ListField.

```
    public int moveFocus(int amount, int status, int time) {
        invalidate(getSelectedIndex());
        return super.moveFocus(amount, status, time);
    }
```

Vivek's method works well for single fields outside of a ListField row though.

Answer (score 1):

use invalidate() function within onfocus() and onunfocus() method.

For example if you use LabelField then use:

```
LabelField l=new LabelField("Hello",FOCUSABLE)
        {
            protected void onFocus(int direction) 
            {
                invalidate();
                super.onFocus(direction);
            }
            protected void onUnfocus() 
            {
                invalidate();
                super.onUnfocus();
            }
        };
```

Comment: First, thanks a lot!  This solution worked perfectly for some of my problems.  I only think the onUnfocus() is required.  The problem I'm still having is with ListField rows.  I tried overriding onUnfocus() for the entire ListField as well as the individual TableRowManager objects that I'm using to contain my list rows but no dice.

Comment: also need to call invalidate() method in drawListRow() function and paint() function. Actually invalidate() method need to call when UI change. When any field gain focus then basiclly it's draw a blue color rectangle i.e. Ui have changed.